# Magento2.3.0 any one use layered navigation with multi select checkbox using category and other attribute filter

Tags: frontend, layered-navigation, magento2.3.0, sidebar, multiselect-attribute

I am using Magento2.3.0 community version and I have integrate all free version layer navigation but not working  so my requirement is attribute option with checkbox  select than not remove in existing filter section inside.so if any one know this type of feature available in extension please reply me link and name and compatible with my magneto version.

Thanks in advance